# Conversão de NSString para NSDictionary sempre nulo

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou convertendo NSString para NSDictionary porém quando passo dentro de uma variável sempre retorna nulo.

o que eu estou fazendo:

```
NSDictionary *json =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: nil];
```

Onde body é a minha variável, porém se coloco o conteúdo dela ali tudo funciona normal!

O que poderia estar acontecendo?

```
conteúdo da variável: @"{\"teste\" : \"ehtetra\"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
NSString *suaString = @"{\"teste\" : \"ehtetra\"}";

NSData *data = [suaString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id novoJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"JsonOutput:%@",novoJson);
```